# What can be improved with this SHOWPLAN?

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following query which can take up to 30 seconds to execute...

```
DECLARE @id int = NULL
DECLARE @sh nvarchar(10) = NULL

SELECT wm.Id, stl.Key, rrrwm.Id
FROM wm
INNER JOIN wmstp ON wm.Id = wmstp.Id and wmstp.Status = 'A'
    AND (@id IS NULL OR wm.id = @id)
INNER JOIN stl ON wmstp.Key = stl.Key
    AND wmstp.Code = stl.Code and stl.Status ='A' and stl.Type = 'LB'
    AND (@sh IS NULL OR wmstp.Key = @sh)
INNER JOIN ma ON stl.Key = ma.Key AND ma.Status = 'Y'
INNER JOIN mac ON ma.Id = mac.Id AND mac.Status = 'Y'
INNER JOIN maca ON mac.Id = maca.Id
LEFT JOIN rrr ON ma.Id = rrr.Id
LEFT JOIN rrrwm ON rrr.Id = rrrwm.Id
GROUP BY wm.Id, stl.Key, rrrwm.Id
ORDER BY stl.Key ASC
```

The `SHOWPLAN` tells me this:

1. Parallelism (Gather Streams) Cost: 14%
2. Sort (Distinct Sort) Cost: 25%
3. Clustered Index Seek (Clustered) [maca] Cost: 21%
4. Clustered Index Scan (Clustered) [ma] Cost: 9%
5. Clustered Index Seek (Clustered) [stl] Cost: 15%

All of these tables have indexes, so what can I do to improve the query time on SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Paste the plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and show us the table structures of the tables involved, and tell us all about any indexes that are present on those tables

Comment: I feel that exposes rather too much internal company information. Shame there isn't an obfuscate option on that tool.

Comment: Try taking out the `GROUP BY` and changing the joins to `EXISTS`. SentryOne Plan Explorer can obfuscate it for you, then share it via pastetheplan